# Why does one code execute from one folder but not the other?

Tags: ruby, windows

I was just curious as to why with Windows O/S a simple Ruby file that prints one line to the command prompt can execute correctly from one path, but not the other.

Currently, I have said file in `C:\Ruby193\test\lib` saved inside the `lib` folder. When I go to the command prompt and set the path to `C:\Ruby193\test\lib`, I'd expect to see the code string be printed to the command prompt. However, nothing but an empty line is produced, and if I go up the path and set it to `C:\Ruby193\test` and execute the ruby file from there, it works just fine.

Does anyone have a sound explanation as to why it works that way? Would this also be the same case for a MAC O/S as well?

Comment: Could we see the script?

Comment: Well, it should work just fine if you have exported the environment path vars fine (`PATH`). Did u do it already ?

Comment: This was the entire script:

'puts "EventManager Initialized!"'

Comment: Pamio - How do I go about doing that? Can you forward me to a tutorial?